# SQLite Update Method Not Failing for Invalid datatype

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm having a strange problem with an SQLite Database, specifically with data validation on an UPDATE query. So let me begin, if i use the following query, i get a 'datatype mismatch' error when i try to run it. This is correct and expected because the field type is marked as an integer.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Table ('Column') VALUES ('shouldFail')
```

However, one would also expect that the following UPDATE query should return the same 'datatype mismatch' error, but it doesn't. I can run the following query perfectly fine, which allows me to end up with a 'String' data type in a column which is marked as INTEGER only...

```
UPDATE Table SET 'Column'='shouldFail' WHERE SecondColumn = 'Some value'
```

So can anyone tell me why the SQL datatype validation is working on the first query, but not on the second?

Many Thanks
Sam

Comment: For me, it didnt throw any error in both cases. Take a look at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/71360/2

Comment: How is `Table` declared? Any triggers or checks? (And you should use `Column` instead of `'Column'`.)

Comment: Sorry, the example I gave was a simple example, i am actually processing a few columns so i use ('column','column2', etc)... The column in question within the table is just within a `CREATE TABLE "Table" ("Column" INTEGER NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

With my MySQL knowledge I'd say that `REPLACE` is not an `UPDATE`, it's an `DELETE, THEN INSERT`. Further I bet your database is set to raise only a warning when a row is updated with wrong datatype and the value is set to default value (0 for integer). Inserts fail, updates raise warnings. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with sqlite, but I heard somewhere they are not that different?

P.S.: Try `SHOW WARNINGS;` and see if there's something...

Comment: I should add that i'm using the FMDB wrapper from within an iOS application. I don't have the option to show warnings, as far as i can see.